# Handling Conditional GETs via redirects with Volley

Tags: android, redirect, http-redirect, http-caching, android-volley

I have an issue using Volley with conditional GETs on cached responses when the request goes through one or more redirect hops.

On the initial request, if the server responds with a 302, the HTTP stack (I'm using the default HurlStack) transparently follows the redirect(s) and ultimately returns the response from the final server.

On subsequent requests, Volley adds an If-Modified-Since header to perform a conditional GET, but these are sent to the initial server, so instead of redirecting we just get a 304 response and the request never reaches the final server.

Since Volley is very loosely coupled with its underlying HTTP stack, there's no way to communicate the fact that the cache headers should only be sent with the final request.

The best solution that I can see (besides never sending conditional GETs) is to write a custom HttpUrlConnection implementation that recognizes that certain headers belong to a specific URL and only sends those headers when appropriate. This means, I would have to save the URL of the final server somewhere, probably as a custom header so that it is saved in the cache along with the other headers.

A slightly less hacky solution would be to write a custom HttpStack implementation that handles redirects manually. But that would mean we could not reuse the connection for redirects to the same host, so it would be less efficient.

Has anyone else run into this issue and have a better solution? It doesn't seem to be specific to Volley or HttpUrlConnection, but to any HTTP library that handles redirects transparently. How do you tell it which headers go with a given URL?